# How to invert Regex match operator when using it in ternary operators?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to check if the initial `Thiswindow` variable contains `AHK_ID` or `A`, if it does NOT then assign `111` else assign `000`

The below, always assigns `111` to `ThisWindow`, I would like it to NOT in this case, cant the operator `~=` not be inverted, like so `!~=` or even `~!=`?

```
ThisWindow := "Ahk_ID 0x12345"
ThisWindow := ThisWindow ~!= "Ahk_ID 0x" || ThisWindow != "A" ? "111"  : "000"
OutputDebug, %ThisWindow%
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operators are operators, you don't invert operators, but you can invert statements:
`!(ThisWindow ~= "Ahk_ID 0x")`

Though, it seems like to me that you should just reorder the logic a bit and you don't even need any unnecessary inverting etc:
`ThisWindow := (ThisWindow ~= "Ahk_ID 0x" || ThisWindow == "A") ? "000" : "111"`
And you were also missing parenthesis around the or-statement for the ternary.

---

Test code:

```
for each, title in StrSplit("Ahk_ID 0x12345,A,Asd", ",")
    outputs .= title ": " ((title ~= "Ahk_ID 0x" || title == "A") ? "000" : "111") "`n"

MsgBox, % outputs
```

Output:

```
Ahk_ID 0x12345: 000
A: 000
Asd: 111
```

Comment: Now I understand better, thanks